# EntityManager.merge(x) causes "select" query to DB

Tags: hibernate, jpa, optimistic-locking, detach

I'm using Hibernate as JPA implementation. In my vaadin application `EntityManager` is request-scoped (to avoid uncontrolled commit of accumulated changes). I store detached entity in session and reattach it every time it is needed in request (once per request, I check this using `em.contains()`). Entity references another entity, that one references another one, so in the end I have three-level cascade-all tree graph with said session-scoped entity as a root.

This works fine until I have large completely new tree with completely new nodes (totally over 5000 items) - Hibernate tries to **find** each new node on merge (I can see its attempts in my logs - many `select`s by unexisting ids). Is this a bug or it's just me misusing JPA?

**Update**

I don't use `@Version` field.

**Update***

In my app I use same approach for storing all entity subtrees regardless of structure of cascading relationships, so I can't differentiate between different use cases, and therefore I use merge.

Comment: Do you have `@Version`fields? Can you show the relevant parts of your entities(the ID fields & the relationships between them)?

Comment: @Andrei I don't use `@Version` fields (as I thought it's only needed when dealing with record locking). Are there any consequences or rules to use `@Version` field? (updated description)

Comment: No special rules (beside the type), but consequences may be (depending on the implementation), because the Optimistic Locking means comparing the `@Version` field with the current data in DB (which could mean a select). You didn't post anything of your code.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use `entityManager.persist()` for the completely new tree instead of `entityManager.merge()` in order to avoid the new selects. `merge()` can be used for both new and persisted entities, and hibernate have to decide what to do (SQL inserts or updates), and for that it needs those selects.

Comment: Ok, I see your point. But there are two next points:

1) I had bad expirience with `Eclipselink` and `persist()` - on `persist()` Eclipselink tries to store all object tree regardless cascading settings. So, a plenty of code was written based on this behavior, and when the problem was seen (`merge()` takes into account cascade types), it was too late to change the code. I want to avoid these situations in future (regardless of JPA provider).

2) If I load root object (and then add 5000 children), `persist()` is no use anymore.

Comment: 1. I doubt EclipseLink (or any other JPA providers) ignores the cascading settings on persist(), but that deserves (or deserved when you had the problem) an entire separate question. 2. Of course you cannot use persist for an already existing object, but your code should know better when to call a persist() and merge(), as they are different scenarios.

Comment: I can't find now the article about this behavior (article, bug ticket, etc, that all had it's place at that time). About code - at the end, there is no difference wether you create or update entity, as there are always could be new child entities (in our app we use one approach for all entities, so entity subtree **might** or **might not** have cascaded relationships). I appreciate your answer though. Maybe you could suggest something in the light of new details I provided in my comments?